# Allow different GWT visual themes for different users

Tags: gwt

My question is this: how do you allow a different GWT visual theme depending on the user that logs in?
I would like to decide which theme to use when the customer logs in (that is before the GWT app gets loaded, so I am pretty sure it should be possible).
I have attempted to use class replacement based on a custom-property, but that failed because only the last inherited module's set of images become visible, even though I can select the right css file... I have searched everywhere and can't find the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion Thomas, but the problem with this solution is that you're assuming the CSS stylesheet is available for me to add to a ClientBundle (I tried that but unless you copy the css file and accompanying pics to your project, you can't do that). The themes come from external GWT modules. And I would like to keep it this way for modularity (it would be painful to import a whole bunch of resources into my project every time we needed a new theme).

The work-around I came up with was to write the injection code myself (just inject a link tag in the HTML head) at run-time.
For completeness, here's the code to do it:

```
protected void doInjection(String cssFilePath) {
    // <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="sol.css">
    Element headEl = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("head").getItem(0);
    HeadElement head = HeadElement.as(headEl);
    LinkElement link = Document.get().createLinkElement();
    link.setType("text/css");
    link.setRel("stylesheet");
    link.setHref(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + cssFilePath);
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

And you call this method with something like this:

```
doInjection("gwt/standard/standard.css");
```

Then, inherit all Resources modules from your project's GWT module file. For example:

```
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.StandardResources'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.DarkResources'/>
```

Inheriting the *Resources version of the Module avoids automatically injecting the style-sheet.

To decide which theme to use, I created a custom GWT property in the module file, based on the value of this property, I replace a default Java class (which would just insert the default theme) with a different Java class (which subclasses the default class) if a different theme should be used. This has the added bonus that I can include my own ResourceBundle resources within each theme, because the replacement Java class used with a theme, besides injecting the right css file, can also provide alternative Resources to my GWT code.

**EDIT**

I would like to add one important note:
The solution described above works quite well. But if your app uses different Locales or other GWT properties, this approach may cause the number of compilation permutations to explode! With only 6 different themes and 3 different Locales, on top of the standard 6 different browser versions you normally have, the GWT compiler will create 6 x 3 x 6 = 108 different compilations!! This is pretty crazy!!

A better solution, which I decided to follow after all, is to set an attribute into the HttpSession once the user logs in, and then based on the value of this attribute, load the appropriate css file (first thing in the onModuleLoad() of my entry-point class). The only difference from the solution described above is on how you select the theme.

Answer (score 1):

I use a different approach, which mostly relies on the power of CSS with a single line of GWT code to switch themes.

First, define the themes that you want to apply. I use an enum.

```
public enum Theme {
    DARK,
    BRIGHT;
}
public static String getDefault() {
    return BRIGHT.name();
}
```

Now, when you launch an app, apply a default theme (`Theme.getDefault()`). When a user selects a different theme, apply it:

```
public static void setTheme(String theme) {
   /*
    * Setting style on Body element allows us to "theme" the RootPanel as well.
    */

    Document.get().getBody().setClassName(theme);
}
```

When you apply a new theme, the look of your app will instantly change without reloading the page.

Finally, define all theme elements that you need in your CSS file:

```
.DARK {background: #000; color: #CCC}
.BRIGHT {background: #ebebeb; color: #000}

.gwt-DialogBox {border-radius: 6px}
.DARK .gwt-DialogBox {border: 3px solid #555}
.BRIGHT .gwt-DialogBox {border: 3px solid #CCC}
```

Notice that you only add a theme selector in front of rules that are different for different themes.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using `setClassName` on the root document instead of `RootPanel.get().setStyleName(theme)` or `RootPanel.get().setStylePrimaryName(theme)`?

Comment: The key reason is that RootPanel often already has some class names. These other classes will not be "themed". In  other words, the selector ".DARK .myApp" will not work if you apply both "DARK" and "myApp" to RootPanel. I have not tried to use setStylePrimaryName() and setStyleDependentName() for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following general approach:

1. Define one CSS file for each of the visual themes.
2. Put them all in a [ClientBundle](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/resources/client/ClientBundle.html) as described [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource).
3. Hold off injecting the themed CSS until you've authenticated the user. You can inject the general CSS you need for displaying the login screen.
4. Then inject the themed CSS depending on the user using the CssResource's ensureInjected() method.